# google authentication using angular2

Tags: rest, angular, oauth-2.0, jwt

I have an API that requires google auth2 authentication, and this is how it works tell now.

- the client access /login/google
- the server redirect him to google authentication page
- google send him back to server with a special code
- the server use that code to fetch more data about the current user
  from google
- at the end the server save the user information to db and returns a
  bearer token as a response to client

the only problem here is that the client is an angular2 app and I don't know how to get that bearer from server.

I think about adding a login button, that open a frame to /login/google and at the end of authenticarion workflow I have to get the bearer and close the frame.
but again I don't know if that's possible and if there is a better solution.

thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you sort this?

Comment: well I had no choice but to hardcode to the angular app address in the server code, that way I can redirect the user to that address with a bearer in the query string